# Why when faking a click on a link with document.getElementById("tabkategorierna").click(); all links stops working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a link`(link1)` in my top navbar that opens a sliding down menu with links to different page(on desktop) . It sets a flag and then checks if it is opened or not when you click the link.(this works as it should-opening and closing the menu)

```
var flagga=true;
$$(document).on("click",".openstoramenyn", function(){

    if(flagga){
       $$(document).find('.storamenyn').animate({"top":"59px"}, { duration:300, easing: 'linear'});
       flagga = false;
    }else{
       $$(document).find('.storamenyn').animate({"top":"-"+hojden+"px"}, { duration:300, easing: 'linear'});
       flagga = true;
    }

});
```

Then in that menu I have a link`(link2 with id=tabkategorierna)` that opens the popup menu.

Now, if I click on the `link2` to open a popup menu it works every time to open the popup menu and `link1` is always working.

But if I instead open the popup with the key event `"s"`(for search) then after the popup menu is closed, `link1` is not working anymore - it won´t open the top menu!?

When I click on the key `"s"` on my keyboard I run a click event on the `id=tabkategorierna` to trigger it to fake a click on the link with `id=tabkategorierna`.

So this is the code for opening the popup with the key `"s"` and faking a click on the `id=tabkategorierna` link.

```
var mykeysearchFunc;
mykeysearchFunc = function(event) {
  //o=79 s=83 f=70
  if ((event.keyCode === 79) || (event.keyCode === 83) || (event.keyCode === 70)){
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("tabkategorierna").click();
    console.log(flagga)
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  if ((event.keyCode === 67) || (event.keyCode === 27)){
    app.popup.close(); 
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", mykeysearchFunc)
```

So why does it work if I actually click on the link to open the popup menu and not when it is opened by running `document.getElementById("tabkategorierna").click();`
What is the difference between actually clicking on the link and run the fake click on it?

Why does link1 stop working after I run `document.getElementById("tabkategorierna").click();` ?

Any help really appreciated, thanks.

If you click on the top "MENY" and then"TEST KATEGORIER" you will get the popup menu. if you just hit enter it will close and load a page. Thats how it should work. Now, if you instead open the popup menu with the key "s", it opens the popup menu and then you hit enter and it will load the search page again as it should. But now comes the problem, if you click on the first link you clicked the "MENY", it will not work anymore. That is my problem. https://xn--tervinnmera-w8a.se

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: No Im afraid not, but I can send you a mail if you want to look at it, I really appreciate the help. I don´t want to post the address here since I don´t want this post to show up when searching my domain name.

Comment: A jsfiddle is this website https://jsfiddle.net/. You can post the code you are working with so I check it out for you

Comment: Thanks, but I think I have to create almost the hole site for the problem to show so isn´t it better if you look at the real site? I have updated my question with the link to my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the animation when it has completed its action. It is hijacking other page elements from working on your page.

Try this code:

`$$(document).find('.storamenyn').stop();`

You can refer to this https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Thanks a lot. But that is not the problem. I tested but it still does´t work. And the problem is when I open the popup menu with a fake click, that is making the link1 not to work. So the problem is using the fake click,  somehow it prevents the link1 menu or other links to work after it has run.

Comment: Did you try creating a function that you can call instead of faking the click?

Comment: Yes I created the mykeysearchFunc ? In the above code. Or do you mean something else? :-)

Comment: Ok so I didm´t use the document.getElementById("tabkategorierna").click();, instead I used the function that was called when you ran the fake click. And I think it works now. It looks like it but I have to test some more tomorrow :-) Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: Nice. Glad to be of help